# adding to a set STL - C++

Tags: c++

I have a media program. i am adding CD,dvd,book info. I managed to get the book info added to the set. I am now adding the CD info. I have most of the Cd info added but i have a seperate function for adding band members. thats where i need help!

I am getting a cast error: error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const Item *const ' to 'CD'

CD.h

```
#ifndef CD_H
#define CD_H
#pragma once
#include "item.h"

class CD : public Item
{
public:

    CD(const string& theTitle, const string& theBand, const int snumber);
    const string addBandMember(const string& member);
    const int getNumber() const;
    const string getMusician() const;

    const string getBand() const;
    virtual void print(ostream& out) const;
    ~CD();


private:

    string band;
    string musicians;
    string title;
    int number;

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CD* cd);

#endif
```

CD.cpp

```
const string CD::addBandMember(const string &member)
{

    return this->musicians = member;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Library::addBandMember` you're trying to cast a pointer  to a class type
you need to cast to `CD*` not `CD`

And you probably don't want the 2 const in

```
const Item* const musicCD
```

since you want to modify the `musicCD` !

finally your `CD::addBandMember` method doesn't seem to add a band member but replace it.

Comment: yes but you need to cast it to a >>pointer<< to a CD. you can't cast a pointer to a CD it makes no sense -- you edited your comment before I could send mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the signature of

> void Library::addBandMember(const
>   Item* const musicCD, const string&
>   member)

to

> void Library::addBandMember(const
>   Item* musicCD, const string&
>   member)

as addBandMember() method does indeed change your Item instance, so Item cannot be const. 
Then you need to cast it to CD* using dynamic_cast, because it is a downcast.

Comment: problem is CD has its own class it inherits item. So, there is no musicCD.addband since it dont exist in item. it exists in CD class.

Comment: Oops, right. Then you need to cast, prefferably with dynamic_cast.